# Where can I find a table of TCP header options, which lists the kind number and corresponding option

Tags: networking, tcp

Several days ago I came across a table of common TCP header options (tens of them), which lists the kind number and corresponding option, now I can't find it through `google`.

like

```
kind                 option
0 (8 bits) –       End of options list
1 (8 bits) –       No operation (NOP, Padding) 
2,4,SS (32 bits) – Maximum segment size (see maximum segment size) [SYN]
3,3,S (24 bits) –  Window scale (see window scaling for details) [SYN][7]
4,2 (16 bits) –    Selective Acknowledgement permitted
....
....
```

Can anyone provide a link where I can find such a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 3 "Official" options a network stack must support are the ones defined in [RFC 793 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-18)

```
  Kind     Length    Meaning
  ----     ------    -------
   0         -       End of option list.
   1         -       No-Operation.
   2         4       Maximum Segment Size.
```

Everything else beyond those 3 are "extensions" and are not required to be handled.

From [RFC 1122 Section 4.2.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-85):

> A TCP MUST be able to receive a TCP option in any segment. A TCP MUST
> ignore without error any TCP option it does not implement, assuming
> that the option has a length field (all TCP options defined in the
> future will have length fields). TCP MUST be prepared to handle an
> illegal option length (e.g., zero) without crashing; a suggested
> procedure is to reset the connection and log the reason.

There have been RFC's that add more options (like [RFC 2581](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2581) and [RFC 5681](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681) for congestion control) but those are still considered optional and not all network hardware is required to respect them.

---

If you really want the list of options that have been standardized here is the list from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)

> Some options may only be sent when SYN is set; they are indicated below as [SYN]. Option-Kind and standard lengths given as (Option-Kind,Option-Length).
>
> - 0 (8 bits) – End of options list
> - 1 (8 bits) – No operation (NOP, Padding) This may be used to align option fields on 32-bit boundaries for better performance.
> - 2,4,SS (32 bits) – Maximum segment size (see maximum segment size) [SYN]
> - 3,3,S (24 bits) – Window scale (see window scaling for details) [SYN]
> - 4,2 (16 bits) – Selective Acknowledgement permitted. [SYN] (See selective acknowledgments for details)
> - 5,N,BBBB,EEEE,... (variable bits, N is either 10, 18, 26, or 34)- Selective ACKnowledgement (SACK) These first two bytes are followed
>   by a list of 1–4 blocks being selectively acknowledged, specified as
>   32-bit begin/end pointers.
> - 8,10,TTTT,EEEE (80 bits)- Timestamp and echo of previous timestamp (see TCP timestamps for details)
> - 14,3,S (24 bits) – TCP Alternate Checksum Request. [SYN]
> - 15,N,... (variable bits) – TCP Alternate Checksum Data.
>
> (The remaining options are obsolete, experimental, not yet
> standardized, or unassigned)

Comment: thanks, but I want to get the lists of remaining options, do you know where is it?

Comment: *"The remaining options are obsolete, experimental, not yet standardized, or unassigned"* So they are no other standard ones. I could make one up right now and it would be just as valid as any other options that are not on the above list. If you explained **WHY** you wanted this list maybe we could help you answer your question better.